# Is it possible to create generic selector using PropertyInfo?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a function that will do something with the IEnumerable of any given object for example

```
    public class Sales
    {
        public float Next { get; set; }
        public string ProductId { get; set; }
        public float Year { get; set; }
        public float Month { get; set; }
        public float Units { get; set; }
    }
```

where you can see that it is containing property of floats and string
now what I want is to calculate min max from those float properties

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GenericSelector<T>(this IEnumerable<T> dataset)
{
    foreach (var property in typeof(T).GetProperties())
    {
        if(property.PropertyType == typeof(float))
        {
            var min = dataset.Min(x => /*reflection from property variable*/);
            var max = dataset.Max(x => /*reflection from property variable*/;
            /** more calculation of min max from here **/
        }
    }
}
```

is it possible to reflect the property back to selector in this case?

Comment: `var min = dataset.Min(x => (float)property.GetValue(x));`?

Comment: @thepirat000 never thought that it would be this easy, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [PropertyInfo.GetValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getvalue):

```
foreach (var property in typeof(T).GetProperties())
{
    if(property.PropertyType == typeof(float))
    {
        var min = dataset.Min(x => (float)property.GetValue(x));
        var max = dataset.Max(x => (float)property.GetValue(x));
        // ...
    }
}
```